# Turning on Camera with code

Tags: image, raspicam

I found the following code (on `http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-opencv/`)

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("w1", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
camera_index = 0
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)

def repeat():
    global capture #declare as globals since we are assigning to them now
    global camera_index
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("w1", frame)
    c = cv.WaitKey(10)
    if(c=="n"): #in "n" key is pressed while the popup window is in focus
        camera_index += 1 #try the next camera index
        capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
        if not capture: #if the next camera index didn't work, reset to 0.
            camera_index = 0
            capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)

while True:
    repeat()
```

The code compiles great when I ran it via the terminal, but there is no video feed. The camera's red light doesn't turn on (I am using Rasp Pi's camera). I get the following warning:

> GLib -GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property
>   GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised.

I did try using the camera via the python terminal -- i.e., using `raspistill` -- and the camera works. I followed `http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/python/README.md`
Do I need to amend the code below with `import picamera`etc?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hei, can you confirm that you have /dev/video0 ?

Answer (score 5):

OpenCV uses V4L to communicate with web-cams by default. When using the Pi's camera module this means you need to load a V4L driver to expose the camera module as a V4L device (like `/dev/video0`). [This forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=62364) contains details of the foundation's official V4L driver but the short version is:

- Use `sudo rpi-update` to update your firmware (the driver is part of the firmware)
- Use `sudo reboot` to reboot the Pi
- After rebooting, use `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` to load the V4L driver

At this point you should find `/dev/video0` exists and OpenCV should be able to use the Pi's camera module. Control of the camera module (via the V4L driver) requires the `v4l2-ctl` utility. Details for installing this are in the linked forum post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still could not get the feed to come in the dialog box..I did compile openCv properly, did the update...can you please tell me what else I can try?.

Comment: the red light on the camera doesn't appear at all..it does work with raspistill etc.